# How to delete root user group?

Tags: joomla-4.x, user-groups

I transferred all my users from J3! to J4! using JLex Transfer. In my J3! site I had incorrectly created usergroups as root groups. These groups are no longer necessary in my new site. All I have tried is checkmarking them and trying to delete. I get the error "0 Root usergroup cannot be deleted."
Is there a way around this? Or must I live with these root usergroups? They're not really a hastle, just look bad.

[image: Pic of Users: Groups to be deleted "Datubāze", "Db admin", "Skola", "NOBODY", "kasiere"]

Comment: I can't find this error message in Joomla, so maybe it's an extension that you've installed which is preventing the deletion. You could try and find where that error message is located in the language .ini files to identify the extension. Via Joomla you should be able to find it by going to System / Language Overrides, then select the Administrator in the dropdown and click on New. Then in the right hand side search for Value, and enter some text from the error message.